# ¿Tenemos en C++ o C algún gestor de paquetes?

Tags: c++, c

En otros lenguajes de más alto nivel e interpretados, con el paso del tiempo se han ido estableciendo, a veces tras luchas entre diversas opciones, un gestor de paquetes *"de facto"*:

- [<kbd>Composer</kbd>](https://getcomposer.org/) en Php
- [<kbd>Luarocks</kbd>](https://luarocks.org/) en Lua
- [<kbd>Pip</kbd>](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) en Python
- [<kbd>Rubygems</kbd>](https://rubygems.org/) en Ruby
- [<kbd>Yarn</kbd>](https://yarnpkg.com/) en Javascript

### ¿Pero en C o C++ cuáles hay?

Comment: Me sumo, también me interesaría saber jaja !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Gestor de paquetes en el lado cliente**

Los lenguajes que comentas son **todos** interpreteados y ese es un detalle importante.

En los lenguajes interpretados al cliente le tienes que hacer llegar el código fuente ya que será el intérprete que tenga instalado en su máquina el que procesa el script que da forma al programa.

En los lenguajes compilados la situación cambia ya que al cliente final le llega un código binario ejecutable en vez del código fuente.

¿Y este detalle por qué es importante? Pues los motivos son varios:

- El código binario es sensible no solo al Sistema Operativo donde se va a ejecutar. Un binario para Windows no funcionará en Linux
- El código binario puede no funcionar en diferentes versiones del mismo Sistema Operativo. De hecho muchas aplicaciones modernas (por no decir casi todas) que hay en Windows, no van a arrancar en un Windows 95.
- El código binario es más restrictivo que el código fuente. El tamaño de los objetos y la interfaz de las funciones y APIs está grabado a fuego en el código binario, por lo que a un binario no le puedes acoplar cualquier DLL.

Y a grandes rasgos estos motivos, mas algún otro que no he recordado, son los motivos por los que no encuentras gestores de paquetes en lenguajes compilados como C, C++, pascal, ...

**Gestor de paquetes en el lado del desarrollador**

Un problema que nos solemos encontrar al trabajar en C / C++  es que existen numerosos compiladores incluos para el mismo Sistema Operativo. Esto suele ser un inconveniente ya que cada compilador hace ciertas tareas a su manera y ello hace que las librerías de diferentes compiladores puedan no ser compatibles entre sí.

Y luego está el tema de las dependencias. En los lenguajes interpretados las dependencias externas se cuentan con los dedos de la mano, pero en el caso particular de, al menos, C/C++ la cosa cambia y es que en este caso las dependencias pueden ser bastante variopintas. Y claro, el problema de las dependencias aquí es el tema de las licencias... ciertas licencias te obligan a publicar el código fuente de tu aplicación mientras que otras licencias te pueden impedir distribuir tu ejecutable sin pasar por caja... el tema de las licencias es un mundo.

Sin embargo sí que te puedes encontrar gestores de paquetes integrados en ciertos IDE. En estos casos pueden suceder dos cosas:

- Que el IDE sea universal. Aquí solo podría descargarse el código fuente de las librerías. Esta suele ser la opción más común.
- Que el IDE solo trabaje con un compilador. En ese caso es posible que te de la opción de bajarte librerías ya compiladas, lo que te puede ahorrar mucho tiempo.

El inconveniente es que son soluciones a nivel de IDE, por lo que si cambias de IDE seguramente cambien las opciones que tienes disponibles. Eso sí, es probable que estos gestores te ofrezcan versiones de librerías antiguas (mantener los gestores actualizados consume tiempo y dinero), por lo que si tu idea es trabajar con la última versión es probable que te toque descargar y compilar a mano las librerías.

Una última opción que tienes es trabajar con cmake. Este gestor de proyectos, dedicándole algo de tiempo y esfuerzo, puede hacer maravillas en el tema de la gestión de paquetes. Otros *Xmake* también pueden llegar a servir, pero yo personalmente me decantaría por cmake (tienes por ejemplo qmake, pero este sistema va ligado a Qt).

**Conclusión**

En definitiva yo diría que no existe un gestor de paquetes en C/C++. Al menos no de manera universal.

Sí que existen algunas soluciones en esa línea, pero son dependientes del IDE o de un framework en particular.

Comment: Puede que no sea del todo cierto. Golang puede descargar paquetes y es un lenguaje compilado.

Comment: @akko golang es un lenguaje que nacio hace 9 años... c++ tiene unos 40 años. Nacieron en momentos diferentes con requisitos bien distintos. Go se ha aprovechado de todas las mejoras que se han introducido en todos estos años

Comment: @eferion la respuesta me parece útil, pero no satisfactoria en todo y discutible en otros aspectos (el problema de las licencias es similar en el código interpretado...). Estoy dedicándole un tiempo y veo en C++ opciones como conan.io, spak, vcpkg o hunter, que por cierto es la que mejor pinta me tiene al estar integrada en cmake...

Comment: finalmente la puse como la más correcta. Si pudieras completarla con referencias a hunter y conan.io sería de wiki XD grracias @eferion

Answer (score 3):

Si existen, lamentablemente en el ecosistema de C++ los esfuerzos no suelen ser centralizados, ya que se trata de un lenguaje con muchos diferentes compiladores, ports a sistemas operativos y ecosistemas de frameworks y librerías, no hay un claro ganador y no creo que lo haya.

Algunos ejemplos podrían ser:

- [conan](https://conan.io/)
- [vcpkg](https://vcpkg.io/)

Answer (score 1):

Si las librerias están ya instaladas, en linux se puede utilizar las gestores de paquetes del propio sistema operativo. Puedes saber en que paquete esta la la libreria dinámica de cada cabecera con dpkg. Ejemplo:

`dpkg -S /usr/include/Poco/HashTable.h`

Devuelve:

`libpoco-dev:amd64: /usr/include/Poco/HashTable.h`

Sin embargo pueden haber varias librerias en ese paquete, podrías utilizar nm o objdump para tratar de identificar la librería que buscas. A veces el nombre de la misma libreria es un fuerte indicador de a que cabecera esta asociada. Puedes también saber en que paquete esta una cabera que no hayas instalado con apt-file (sirve para paquetes instalados como no instalados). Por ejemplo:

`apt-file search stdout.h`

Allí también te vendría, supongo que en la mayoría de los casos, las librerias asociadas. Puedes utilizar find para conseguir la cabecera de una función si esta instalada, pero esto te puede arrojar resultados ambiguos. Los IDE no se libran del todo de ese problema pero suelen ahorrarte un montón de trabajo. Y nunca esta de más googlear.